# How to remove time from string and convert to date9 format in sas

Tags: sas

Want to convert `date = 2021/06/05 00:00:00` to `date = 05Jun2021`.  I used this code to convert:

```
New date = datepart(date);
```

But that didn't work.  I also used substring to remove the time but seems this method is a bit lengthy.

Comment: What is the type of the SAS variable `date`?  Is it character or numeric with a format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are positive the existing character variable always uses 4 digits for year 2 digits for month number and 2 digits for day of month then a simple INPUT() will work to convert the first 10 characters into a date.

```
new_date = input(date,yymmdd10.);
format new_date date9.;
```

If the length of that date part of the string varies then add a SCAN() function call to take just the first part of the string.

```
new_date = input(scan(date,1,' '),yymmdd10.);
format new_date date9.;
```